# Argument Spacing When Using lw Option for causes Compile Error with Tikz-Network Package

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, width, line, edge

Writing the code with no spaces between the arguments of "`\Edge[h local options i](Vertex i)(Vertex j)`" normally handles processing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex {A} \Vertex [x = 2] {B} \Vertex [x = 2, y = -1] {C}
\Edge[lw = 3pt](A)(B)
\Edge[lw = 5pt](A)(C)
\end {tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

But if there is spacing (whatever that is) between the arguments of "`\Edge[h local options i](Vertex i)`" as shown below:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage {tikz-network}
\thispagestyle {empty}
\begin {document}
\begin {tikzpicture}
\Vertex {A} \Vertex [x = 2] {B} \Vertex [x = 2, y = -1] {C}
% Case 1: space between <[lw = 3pt]> and <(A) (B)>
\Edge[lw = 3pt] (A)(B)
% Case 2 (below): or even if there is a space between <(A)> and <(C)> as below
\Edge[lw = 5pt](A) (C)
\end {tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

I get the following errors in their order as is the spacing in the code above:

Case 1 - Space between <`[lw = 3pt]`> and <`(A)(B)`> returns the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
(A)(B) \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}
! File ended while scanning use of \@edge.
<inserted text>
\pair
<*>17.tex

?
```

Case 2 - Space between <`[lw = 5pt](A)`> and <`(C)`> returns the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfonlayer @ assert @ is @ active ... fonlayer @ isactive
                                                  {0}\expandfter \pgf@ asser ...

1.8 \Edge[lw = 5pt](A) (C)

?
```

Note 1: Putting spacing between <`\Edge`> and <`[h local options i] (Vertex i) (Vertex j)`> returns no error.

Note 2: Examples taken from `Section 2.2`, page 15 of https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-network.

Note 3: Command latexmk and Zathura viewer were used.

Apparently everything is related to using the `lw` (`\Edge` line width size) option.

Comment: @siracusa , but I really "didn't" put space between <\> and <Edge>. Is that what you wanted to know? If so I understand your explanation but that would not be the fact. Forgive me, now I understand where your question came from, I have directly copied the shell terminal code for editing this question, so I got spacing, I will fix that.

Comment: @siracusa correct improper spacing.

Answer (score 2):

The definitions in the package are "at fault" here. Basically it's the intended usage to have no spaces, because the commands are defined like

```
\newcommand*{\Edge}[1][]{\@edge[#1]}%
\def\@edge[#1](#2)(#3){%
…
```

(above are lines 584/585, the definition of `\Edge`)

What that tells you is that TeX expects exactly `\Edge` followed by `[A](B)(C)` (matching the `[#1](#2)(#3)` specification). Providing what I called `A` can be omitted, because of the wrapper `\newcommand` which in the case of the user not providing a value passes an empty argument. The other two arguments in parentheses are still expected by the package macro and they are expected without any spaces.

As a summary: If you want to insert spaces there, you have to redesign and reimplement the package interface.

*Edit:* This has nothing to do with the package, really. You can reproduce the exact same error by a simple code example like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\blub(#1)(#2){#1#2}
\blub(A) (B)
\end{document}
```

That's just how `\def` works. The macro will look for the argument specification as defined.

Comment: I will notify the maintainer of the package at https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network/ and attach the link of your response to the "problem" I opened yesterday on github for this project of his. Thank you for your attention. Include your answer in the following issue https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network/issues/11

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah Well, it's a design decision. I have added another code snippet to illustrate the base problem. And in your issue note 3 is wrong, you can omit the optional argument and still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, I respect the design decision, but let it be with us, if the package maintainer accepts spaces, then let's hope to see what he will do: -) - _-. Although it can be compiled, it is somewhat inconvenient to acquire these errors. I will see note 3 and change or delete it. Grateful for your attention.